# Bucle en expresión regular donde quiero hacer recursión - JavaCC

Tags: java, regex, javacc

Es importante recalcar que el problema es de JavaCC, pero la etiqueta *javacc* todavía no existe en el sitio en español, y no tengo la suficiente reputación para crear la etiqueta.

Llevo bastante rato intentando hacer que JavaCC lea un código de tipo orientado a objetos, sabemos que las clases pueden tener clases, pero teniendo una misma expresión dentro de otra me sale error de bucle, mi código es el siguiente:

```
TOKEN:
{
    <Clase: <DecObjeto> <LlaveIzq> (<Propiedad>)+ <LlaveDer>> |
    <Propiedad: <Metodo> | <Clase> | <Funcion>>
}
```

An intentar compilar me sale este error:

> Error: Line 221, Column 5: Loop in regular expression detected: "...Clase... --> ...Propiedad... --> ...Clase..."

Y entiendo el porqué sale error, pero me gustaría saber cómo poder llevar a cabo esto para poder hacer una recursión y hacer que pueda leer clases dentro de clases.

Busqué acerca del tema y encontré la "eliminacion de recursion izquierda", pero no me quedó muy claro el tema y el cómo se puede aplicar en JavaCC (a pesar de que según JavaCC es de los más usados para estos temas).
Encontré [esta página](https://campusvirtual.ull.es/ocw/pluginfile.php/2208/mod_resource/content/0/perlexamples/node141.html) que explica cómo se hace, pero no me queda muy claro el tema, igual con [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPOLOX6POv4&ab_channel=TusClasesOnline-GradodeInform%C3%A1tica).

Entiendo un poco la idea de la eliminación de recursión izquierda, pero no me queda claro cómo se aplica lo explicado en las fuentes para usarse en JavaCC.

Comment: Una duda el paréntesis de cierre al final de la segunda línea es correcto? <Función>). Dónde se abre ese paréntesis?

Comment: Otro punto, en la Propiedad no puede haber una definición de clase porque no son iguales las propiedades llevan un tipo y nombre de propiedad, por lo tanto no deberías referirse a una clase en propiedad. Si es una sub clase entonces utiliza una expresión subclase- dentro de la propiedad y este último es de tipo clase.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich no, era un error, ya lo corregí, gracias.

Comment: Lista la etiqueta faltante. :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich intenté hacer algo así con otro tipo de etiqueta ClasePrima (por poner un nombre diferente) pero como también tiene propiedades me salía bucle ahora en Propiedad - > ClasePrima -> Propiedad

Comment: Sucede que la recursión se da en el mismo token y lo que estás haciendo es un loop entre token.  ejemplo de recursión podria  clase -> clase + palabra.  Lo anterior es  recursivo porque entra nuevamente a clase, por lo tanto, deberia haber unas definiciones adicionales de clase:  clase -> palabra o clase -> expresion puesto que por aqui van a resolverse. Lo que no puedes hacer es: clase -> propiedad y luego Propiedad -> Clase porque estas entrando de un lado a otro.  Cada token puede ser definido haciendo  referencia a un token específico o por 
 el (mismo + otro token).

Comment: ¿Y si defines <Propiedad> en un token separado? con eso la definición de <Clase> no sería realmente recursiva pero aceptaría clases dentro de clases

Comment: Tienes que ir bajando no subiendo: si clase es Propiedad, entonces, Propiedad deberías se algo como: public | private>+identificador | expresion | palabra clave  pero no puedes  subir a clase nuevamente porque no estás definiendo bien tu gramática.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich sí, el código original está más estructurado, pero no quería complicar tanto la pregunta, fundamentalmente busco poder realizar recursión o algo que no sea como tal pero me permita hacer lo que busco.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich la idea original era poner adentro de la etiqueta Clase algo como (<Propiedad> | <Clase>)+ pero para resumir un poco esa parte por eso lo puse dentro de la etiqueta propiedad.